# Линейный поиск Python

Tags: python

Помогите с задачей.

Напишите программу, которая определяет, встречается ли заданное число x в данном массиве.

Входные данные:

- В первой строке задается одно натуральное число N
- Во второй строке вводятся N чисел – элементы массива
- В третьей строке содержится одно целое число x

Выходные данные

- Вывести `YES`, если число `x` встречается в данном массиве, и `NO` в противном случае.

Пример входных данных:

```
5

1 2 3 4 5

3
```

Выходные данные:

```
YES
```

Вот, что у меня получилось

```
input()
lst = map(int, (input().split()))
n = int(input())
k = 0
for i in lst:         
    if i == n:
        k += 1
print(k)
```

Он у меня просто выводит число, а нужно, чтобы выводил `YES` или `NO`

Comment: python-2.x и python-3.x  - это взаимоисключающие метки. Если вам не важна версия Python, то оставляйте только метку python - не навешивайте все подряд. Если версия важна, то ставьте конкретные метки (опять же, не навешивайте все подряд) - к примеру, python и python-3.x (не думаю, что у вас вопрос специфичный именно для версии 3.5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
N = int(input("Размер массива: ")) # Вводим размер массива
print("Элементы массива:")
lst = [int(input()) for i in range(N)] # Вводим элементы массива
x = int(input("Число x: ")) # Вводим число x

# Проверяем наличие числа в массиве
if x in lst: 
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Пример работы программы:

```
> Размер массива: 5
> Элементы массива:
1
2
3
4
5
> Число x: 3
YES

> Размер массива: 5
> Элементы массива:
1
2
3
4
5
> Число x: 8
NO
```

Comment: Можно сделать так, чтобы 1 2 3 4 5 писать в строчку?